# jGrowl removes my links

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jgrowl

If I put any links in my messages, jGrowl removes them.  Can I have links in jGrowl?

Comment: I've never seen this behavior, are these links coming from server-side in a update, are you sure they're not HTML encoded?

Comment: They are hard coded.  Am I suppose to do this differently?

Answer (score 0):

When I run this code in firebug console, jgrowl show message with clickable link:

```
$.jGrowl('<a href="www.stackoverflow.com">test</a>')
```